# How to use relative imports in python package?

Tags: python, import, package

I know there is a lot on information on this already, but I'm indelibly having to ask since I'm failing to solve this on my own.

I have a local python package that I have installed in path that I'm trying to import into a different project, but I have failed with my import. The project structure is as following where `__init__.py` files are empty.

```
scanner/
    setup.py
    test_import.py
    scanner/
        __init__.py
        pdf_scanner.py
        serializers/
            __init__.py
            serializers_factory.py
   ....
```

in `pdf_scanner.py` I'm trying to import `trade_serializers` from `serializers.py` using:

`from .serializers.serializers_factory import trade_serializers`

But when doing `import scanner.pdf_scanner` in a different unrelated project I'm getting:

```
    from scanner.serializers.serializers_factory import trade_serializers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scanner.serializers'
```

In my `test_import.py` I have the same import statement working, when running the script from the top-level directory `scanner/`. Is that not equivalent as importing the package in a completely different folder? Any help is highly appreciated!

My `setup.py` file:

```
setup(name='scanner',
      version='0.1',
      description='PDF Scanner for broker confirmation notes',
      url='',
      author='',
      author_email='',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['scanner'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: add an `__init__.py` to your root directory (`scanner` in this case).

Comment: @MaskedMan Thank you for the input! Unfortunately I still get the same error, I have added my `setup.py` file code to help debug further. Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: My second guess would be that you have to put the scanner package in your import path of the other app to use.

Comment: Not quite sure if I follow this one. In my other app, that I want to use scanner package in, is importing from installed packages that exist in python `site-packages`.

Comment: So it's actually in the import path, it got interesting for me. I would like to know the answer, if you would mention me there.

Comment: @MaskedMan I sure will, I don’t have high hopes at the moment since I got downvotet. But if a working answer appears I will be sure to mention you! Thank you for taking you time, and thank you för the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the problem was in my `setup.py` file. Where the sub-directories were not installed, to solve this I changed to the following:

```py
setup(name='scanner',
      version='0.1',
      description='PDF Scanner for broker confirmation notes',
      url='',
      author='',
      author_email='',
      license='MIT',
      packages=find_packages(), #CHANGED TO THIS
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: @MaskedMan No real "solution" to my stupid problem, just slow slow debugging

Comment: It's good that your problem is solved, happy coding.